# How to populate a GridView with singe object from LINQ query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I Know how to populate the GridView with a collection of instances.

```
 var newReviews = from r in myEntities.Reviews
                                     orderby r.Id
                                     select r;
            GridView1.DataSource = newReviews.ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

How to retrieve just a single instance in the GridView:

```
 var newReviews = (from r in myEntities.Reviews
                                     orderby r.Id
                                     select r).Single();
         ....
```

Comment: You mean just one among 'N' records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array with one element:

```
var newReviews = (from r in myEntities.Reviews
                  orderby r.Id
                  select r).Single();

GridView1.DataSource = new[]{ newReviews;}
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
var newReviews = (from r in myEntities.Reviews
                                 orderby r.Id
                                 select r).FirstOrDefault();
if(newReviews != null)
{
    var tempList = new List<dynamic>();
    tempList.Add(newReviews);
    GridView1.DataSource = tempList;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using LINQ method `Take()`:

```
var newReviews = from r in myEntities.Reviews
                                 orderby r.Id
                                 select r;
        GridView1.DataSource = newReviews.Take(1).ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();
```